# Caesar Cipher python program looping issue

Tags: python, loops, encryption, caesar-cipher

Okay, so I have gotten this far with a Caesar cipher program in python and cannot see any reason why this doesn't work, but it doesn't... it outputs the new word as 'a' 'a' 'a' (for however many letters were in the word). My guess is its some kind of loop that results in each letter being changed into 'a' but I just can't figure it out. Can anybody out there help me? Thanks.

My code:

```
word = input("please enter the word you wish to encrypt: ")
seperated = list(word)
length = len(word)
alphabet1 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
alphabet2 = ["b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","a"]
length2 = len(alphabet1)
length3 = len(alphabet2)


for eachposition in range(length):
    for letter in range(length2):
            if seperated[eachposition] == alphabet1[letter]:
                    seperated.pop(eachposition)
                    seperated.insert(eachposition, alphabet2[letter])

print(seperated)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some `print` calls to your code and got lots of false positives where `seperated[eachposition] == alphabet1[letter]` was evaluating as `True` when it shouldn't. From that I realised the problem pretty quickly.

You never use `break` from your loop, so here's what's happening:

- I enter "word"
- The loop runs until it finds that the first letter is the same as the letter 'w' in alphabet
- The first letter of separated is set as 'x', due to how your cipher works
- The loop *keeps running*, now testing if the first letter is 'x'

Since your cipher just advances each letter on one, this loop will always run until it reaches the last letter in your list, 'a'.

The simple fix is to use [`break`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops). It will end a `for` loop prematurely. Meaning that when you have replaced a letter, you want to break out of that inner loop and move onto the next character.

```
for eachposition in range(length):
    for letter in range(length2):
        if seperated[eachposition] == alphabet1[letter]:
            seperated.pop(eachposition)
            seperated.insert(eachposition, alphabet2[letter])
            break
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was after. I knew it would be something stupidly simple.

Answer (score 0):

@SuperBiasedMan gave you the working solution for keeping your code, but i would propose a simpler loop for your task(no need for poping and inserting in place since you are iterating orderly in the whole word).

```
new = []
for c in word:
    for i in range(length2):
        if c == alphabet1[i]:
            new.append(alphabet2[i])
            break


new = ''.join(new)
print new
```

Also consider using dictionaries. They come in handy for problems like that.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to convert each character to its ASCII number, ie a = 97, b = 98 etc [asciitable.com](http://www.asciitable.com/) This can be done with ord()

```
num = ord(character) - 97
```

Then you can add the key to obtain a new ascii code and convert it back to a character.  You have use modulo to allow for cycling around from the end to the start of the alphabet.

```
encr_char = chr((num + key)% 26 + 97)
```

You need to add code to handle upper case letter (ascii 65 - 90) and non alphabet characters.  `isupper()` and `isalpha()` will do the job here.

This approach allows for varying the key.